# How to use markerEnd in react to draw an arrow

Tags: javascript, css, svg, reactjs

I want to draw an arrow with react. I found that maker-end is supported, see: [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html). It is called `markerEnd` instead of `marker-end`. It expect a `'url(#markerArrow)'` but it doesn't seem to work in react. How to make an arrow with svg and react?
Here is my approach in a component subclasses render function: It draws the line but not the arrow head.

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <svg className='Line' style={{ height:height, width:width, top:top, left:left }}>
                <defs>
                    <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6"
                            orient="auto">
                        <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style={{fill: '#000000'}} />
                    </marker>
                </defs>
                <line x1={lx1} y1={ly1} x2={lx2} y2={ly2} markerEnd={ 'url(#markerArrow)' }  style={{ stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 2 }} />
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image: Image from the missing arrow head]
There should be an arrow on the bottom left of the red line.

Comment: markerEnd is an attribute, not a style property

Comment: Okay I changed it to <line x1={lx1} y1={ly1} x2={lx2} y2={ly2} markerEnd={ 'url(#markerArrow)' }  style={{ stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 1 }} /> but still no arrow head :(

Comment: does line rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep your `<defs>` tag inside `svg` element

```html
<defs>
  <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6" orient="auto">
    <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" />
  </marker>
</defs>
<svg width=200 height=200>
  <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="100" style="stroke:#006600; marker-end: url(#markerArrow)" />

</svg>



<svg width=200 height=200>
  <defs>
    <marker id="markerArrow1" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6" orient="auto">
      <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="100" style="stroke:#006600; marker-end: url(#markerArrow1)" />

</svg>
```

if this didnt work,try moving `<defs>` outside of react component and place in seperate `svg` in the page.you can check the implementation [here](https://jsbin.com/pobicireqa/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But maker-end is not available in react. Just makerEnd. I moved the <defs> as you said but sadly still no arrow head.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help others who are looking for an implementation of `marker-end` in React:

**Your code is totally correct!**

There is most likely another problem. Perhaps a different element is on top of your `<line>`. You could check that for example by giving all of your elements an `opacity` attribute.